# How to set frame in center xcode

Tags: ios, frame, center

Im making iPhone app using frame, my frame is not in center and it repeats. I want to set in center and I hate when my frames repeats multiple times.

Im using following code:

```
 UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
// picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
// creating overlayView
UIView* overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:picker.view.frame];
// letting png transparency be
overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"f2.png"]];
[overlayView.layer setOpaque:NO];
overlayView.opaque = NO;

picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;

//[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Am I missing something ?
TNX in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "my frame ... repeats"? And how is this connected to Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what you are asking, but maybe changing from frame to bounds could solve you problem:

```
UIView* overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:picker.view.bounds];
```